# unable to delete google contact from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-contacts-api

From offical [google contact api](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#deleting_contacts) docs:

> Deleting contacts
>
> To delete a contact, send an authorized DELETE request to the
>   contact's edit URL.
>
> The URL is of the form:
>
> https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full/{contactId}

simple request to delete returns `401 error` as response.

```
var url = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/"+req.token.body.sub.agent.agentId+"/full/"+result.googleId;
unirest.delete(url)
    .header({
        'Authorization': 'accessToken='+req.token,
        'If-Match': '*',
    })
    .timeout(60000)
    .end(function (res1) {
        console.log('delete success... ', res1);
        res.send(res1);
});
```

**Note:** I tried with `'Authorization': 'Bearer '+req.token,` as well but still the same issue

Comment: @KENdi Really? `userEmail` is authenticated user and I am able to retrieve contact numbers.

Comment: oh my bad, let me check again the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. The problem was with the access Token `(req.token)` I was sending. I was sending object instead of actual token string